# When to use going and by going

Tags: grammaticality

Which is correct?

I save money going to Cecil College or I save money BY going to Cecil College?

Answer (score 1):

> I save money by going to Cecil College

means that by the expedient of going to Cecil College (probably attending this as a less expensive centre of education than other alternatives, but perhaps getting off the bus a stop earlier than you might) you save money. Compare 'I save money by shopping at ASDI'. There is a comparison involved.

> I save money going to Cecil College

may be merely a less formal variant, with preposition deletion. Or it could mean 'I save money because I go to Cecil College [: everyone there has to enrol in a savings scheme]'. Preposition deletion creates ambiguities (however unlikely).